# Using the "setUniformArray" method in the SFML library for a GLSL fragment shader

Tags: c++, fragment, glsl, shader, sfml

I have a problem using the "setUniformArray" method. I want to pass a std::vector to the shader in this way:

```
void OutputShader::setUniform(const std::string &name, const std::vector<float>& arr) {
    outputShader.setUniformArray(name, arr.data(), arr.size());
}
```

In fragment shader I wrote like this:

```
uniform float "vector_name"[];
```

As a result I am getting the error:

```
Uniform "vector_name" not found in shader
```

Can you tell me the cause of the error and how to fix it please

Comment: What about `uniform float vector_name[];`

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved

The fact is that this array was not used anywhere else and it seems that it was "thrown out" during compilation, so when I was trying to set a value to it, an error was generated